# Fileserver no writeaccess with ubuntu but windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu-10.10, file-server

i have no write writing permission on the fileserver, the user has all priviliges. Its working fine with windows! There i can write, but on my ubuntu 10.10 only reading. i've mounted the drive with this command in my fstab:

```
//10.20.30.40/Austausch /media/Austausch cifs username=markey,password=ThePassword  0 0
```

Why iam not allowed to write?

Comment: Not enough information to start diagnosing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append your `uid` and `gid` to the mount options:

```
//10.20.30.40/Austausch /media/Austausch cifs username=markey,password=ThePassword,uid=<x>,gid=<y>  0 0
```

Type `id` to check your id.